# Can a buildbot-step run python code on the worker?

Tags: python, buildbot

I am using [buildbot](https://buildbot.net/). Is it possible to write my own [build-step](https://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/customization.html#writing-new-buildsteps) class that executes Python code on the worker?

The build-step will consist of

- find all files of a certain type in the source
- start a 3rd-party application that is installed on the worker via [PythonCOM](https://mhammond.github.io/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/docindex.html)
- command the started app to do some checks for the files found in step 1
- close the app

Unfortunately the app does not support command line parameters for performing the required operation.

I know I could write my own shell script and have that run on the worker via the [RemoteCommand](https://docs.buildbot.net/current/developer/cls-remotecommands.html) class. But I'd prefer to have all code in one place (in the new build-step) and not having to place such a script on each worker.